# Explode multiple comma-separated strings in a 2d array, then get all unique values

Tags: php, arrays, csv, duplicates, explode

I have an 2d array which returns me this values:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
          [0] => wallet,pen 
          [1] => perfume,pen 
   ) 
   [1] => Array ( 
          [0] => perfume, charger 
          [1] => pen,book 
   ).
```

Out of this i would like to know if it is possible to create a function which would combine the array going this way,and create a new one :

if for example `[0] => Array ( [0] => wallet,pen [1] => perfume,pen )` then should be equal to 
`[0] => Array ( [0] => wallet,pen, perfume )` because there is a common word else do nothing.

And also after that retrieve each words as strings for further operations.

---

How can i make the values of such an array unique. `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => wallet [1] => pen [2] => perfume [3] => pen) )` as there is pen twice i would like it to be deleted in this way `( [0] => Array ( [0] => wallet [1] => pen [2] => perfume) )`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: well it is the result of combining 2 arrays

Comment: Nobody will write whole code for you. You have to use own brain and try to write it. If you fail - you can show your code and somebody will help you. This is how stackoverflow works.

Comment: im not looking for codes but for hints, if you have an idea of a better data structure i could be using

Comment: @StringerB i will provide you the tools, and it's up to you to try. The functions you need to get this job done: `loops, explode(), implode(), trim()`. Good coding !

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of mapping the array and combining the inner arrays:

```
$x = [['wallet,pen', 'perfume,pen'], ['perfume,charger', 'pen,book']];

$r = array_map(function($item) {
    return array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(function($subitem) {
        return explode(',', $subitem);
    }, $item)));
}, $x);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4RY4lv)

This first splits all the strings based on comma. They are then merged together with `array_merge()` and the duplicates are removed using `array_unique()`.

See also: [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array), [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$array = Array (Array ( "wallet,pen", "perfume,pen" ), Array ( "perfume, charger", "pen,book" ));
$res   = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
   $temp  = array();
   foreach($val as $k=>$v){
     foreach(explode(",",$v) as $vl){
        $temp[]  = $vl;
     }
   }
   if(count(array_unique($temp)) < count($temp)){
     $res[$key] = implode(",",array_unique($temp));
   }
   else{
     $res[$key] = $val;
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => wallet,pen,perfume
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => perfume, charger
            [1] => pen,book
        )

)
```

Comment: i tried your way but seems like it works just once, I added an array with similar values and it did not do nothing. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate duplicate values while pushing them into your result array by assigning the tag as the key to the element -- PHP will not allow duplicate keys on the same level of an array, so any re-encountered tags will simply be overwritten.

You can use recursion or statically written loops for this task.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/q2Rad))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $tags) {
        foreach (explode(',', $tags) as $tag) {
            $result[$tag] = $tag;
        }
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9urYn))

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($v) use(&$result) {
        foreach (explode(',', $v) as $tag) {
            $result[$tag] = $tag;
        }
    }
);
var_export(array_values($result));
```